# Filtering out multiples from DENSE_RANk

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, dense-rank

So I have a dataset of bus times where some of the data was recorded incorrectly and duplicated. The query looks like this

I'm a noob as you can tell and I haven't figured out how to make this look like the nice sql codes y'all have. Trying to learn!

I think I simplified my query too much, thinking the answer would be more simple. Here is the actual query

The problem I'm running into in this data set, is that the same time will be mark down for multiple stops as the time recorded, which is impossible. I want to see what the data would look like if I were to omit those rows, as it is giving me false information

SELECT

> route_id,

> trip_id,

> trip_date,

> aimed_arrival_time,

> CASE
> when (datetime_diff(time_recorded, aimed_arrival_time, SECOND)/60) >= 1400 THEN date_add(time_recorded, INTERVAL 1 day)
> when (datetime_diff(time_recorded, aimed_arrival_time, SECOND)/60) <= -1400 THEN date_add(time_recorded, INTERVAL 1 day)
> ELSE time_recorded
> END
> AS time_recorded_adj,

> DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY trip_id, trip_date ORDER BY time_recorded) as stop_time_order

FROM

> `bigquery-public-data.san_francisco_transit_muni.stop_monitoring`

WHERE

> time_recorded >= '2020-01-01'

GROUP BY

> route_id,

> trip_id,

> trip_date,

> aimed_arrival_time,

> time_recorded

ORDER BY

> trip_id,

> trip_date,

> aimed_arrival_time

Results look something like this:

| trip_id | expect_arrival_time | recorded_arrival_time | stop_ranks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001444 | 2021-06-20 22:14:19 UTC | 2021-06-20 22:15:52 UTC | 1 |
| 10001444 | 2021-06-20 22:17:07 UTC | 2021-06-20 22:19:52 UTC | 2 |
| 10001444 | 2021-06-20 22:19:00 UTC | 2021-06-20 22:19:52 UTC | 2 |
| 10001444 | 2021-06-20 22:32:26 UTC | 2021-06-20 22:31:59 UTC | 3 |

What I'd like to be able to do is filter out any time the dense rank has multiples so i'd want a query that returns this

| trip_id | expect_arrival_time | recorded_arrival_time | stop_ranks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001444 | 2021-06-20 22:14:19 UTC | 2021-06-20 22:15:52 UTC | 1 |
| 10001444 | 2021-06-20 22:17:07 UTC | 2021-06-20 22:19:52 UTC | 2 |
| 10001444 | 2021-06-20 22:32:26 UTC | 2021-06-20 22:31:59 UTC | 3 |

Any way I could do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try below

```
SELECT
  trip_id,
  MIN(expect_arrival_time) as expect_arrival_time,
  recorded_arrival_time,
  DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY trip_id ORDER BY recorded_arrival_time) as stop_ranks
FROM bus_trips
GROUP BY trip_id, recorded_arrival_time
```

with output

[image]

Comment: May as well use ROW_NUMBER at that point.  Using DENSE_RANK would imply to me that ties are expected, but the GROUP BY eliminates them...

Comment: you are right! logically, ROW_NUMBER will fit better here! :o)

Comment: @MatBailie can you explain why? I'm not entirely sure, My thinking behind using DENSE_RANK was so that I could easily identify the stops where the recorded_arrival_time was repeated.

Comment: i thought I answered your exact question - what is still a problem? please explain

Comment: The ouput from this code didn't yeild the results I needed. I updated the code to show the full code I used, I thought a simplified code would do the trick but I think I needed to show the full picture. I tried the MIN() function and I still get the rows I'm trying to eliminate